# ctest - run tests having 2 labels

Tags: label, ctest

lest assume I have some project that consists of N domains (D1, D2, ... , DN) . Each domain has tests of two kinds: lest say UT and MT. They are defined like so:

```
add_test(
  NAME Di_UT
  COMMAND <blah>
)

add_test(
  NAME Di_MT
  COMMAND <blah>
)
```

And I'd like to be able to filter them by labels. So I add the labels:

```
set_tests_properties(Di_UT PROPERTIES LABELS "UT;Di")
set_tests_properties(Di_MT PROPERTIES LABELS "MT;Di")
```

Then I execute ctest:

```
ctest -L Di
```

will execute all tests for domain Di, and of course the opposite:

```
ctest -L UT
```

Will execute all tests with UT label.

But how to filter by both labels? execute only UT for domain Di?

From what i observe, passing multiple `-L` causes them to overwrite. (the last one has effect). Any other ideas? my cmake version is

`ctest version 3.13.4`

Comment: This was filed upstream as a feature request in https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21087 and is beint worked on in MR https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/5329 so **hopefully** with CMake 3.21 the answers below will be obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that such thing is simply not supported. So as a workaround, I am simply adding a 3rd label containig the other two - and then pas it to ctest. So:

```
add_test(
  NAME Di_UT
  COMMAND <blah>
)

set_tests_properties(Di_UT PROPERTIES LABELS "UT;Di;UT-Di")

add_test(
  NAME Di_MT
  COMMAND <blah>
)
set_tests_properties(Di_MT PROPERTIES LABELS "MT;Di;MT-Di")
```

So then i can execute like so:

execute all UT:

```
ctest -L UT
```

execute all Tests for domain Di:

```
ctest -L Di
```

execute only UT for Di:

```
ctest -L Ut-Di
```

This seems only available option.

Answer (score 2):

The possibility to use regexes in `-L` has been added in (at least) v3.21, see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#label-matching)

Comment: nice :) will remember about this next time

Comment: The `-L` and `-LE` arguments always did regex matching, but v3.21 finally documented this and also changed the behavior when given multiple `-L` or `-LE` arguments

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this too. It's such a pity that such feature is not supported, especially if you consider that the logical or works:

```
ctest -L 'label1|label2'
```

What I came up with is to create my own bash function which boils down to the following:

```
ctest -R "$(echo "$(ctest -N -L label1 | awk '/Test #/ { print $3}')" | tr '\n' '|')" -L label2
```

I know, it's a bit ugly, but let's break it down.

1. You ask ctest to give you all the tests with label1 (-N, so you only list them).
2. Then use awk to extract the test name (without the string `Test #xyz:` first).
3. Then you put all those lines into a single regexp, by replacing `\n` with `|`.
4. You use this string as a regexp for ctest, *combined* with a request for a new label. This makes ctest run tests which have label2 *and* match any of the test names you found at step 1.

It's quite cumbersome, especially if you want to run tests that have N labels.

Answer (score 0):

Based on local testing, with CMake 3.18.2, multiple labels are not respected, it just listens to the final one

```
ctest -L Di -L UT <--- equivalent to ctest -L UT
```

This is consistent with your findings for CMake 3.13.4. The logical `|`  operator *is* supported because the labels use regex matching under the hood:

```
ctest -L "Di|UT" <-- all tests that have either label
```

Unfortunately, the logical `&` operator is not.

In CMake 3.21, they [added documentation of label matching behavior](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/manual/ctest.1.html#label-matching) in [this issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21087) and [merge request](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/5329). Testing with CMake+CTest 3.21.3 indicates the default behavior for multiple label arguments changed:

```
ctest -L Di -L UT <--- only tests that have both labels
```

which matches the new documentation

> Using more than one `-L` option means "match **all** of these".

tl;dr: if possible, upgrade to CMake 3.21+